# Outlook plugin which required user input while installing

Tags: c#, plugins, outlook

I am trying to create an Outlook plugin which will ask the user couple of Question like URL/Username etc when they try to install the plugin. Then want to save those data in a text file which can be access later on when needed.

Can someone please help me with this. I am very new in Plugin development.

Thanks

Comment: First you have to mention what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Hi, i don know any way of doing it. I have a Outlook plugin which read emails right now. But need to get user input before installing it.

Answer (score 0):

If your adddin is not configured on startup, display the necessary prompts when it is used for the very first time.